# Field variables inside an Unnamed struct and union

Tags: c++, struct, unions

What is the meaning of having some fields inside a struct inside a union in C++?  I found this from a piece of code from the "Math for game developers" video series in YouTube:

```
private:
    union {
        struct {
            float m_x,m_Y;
        };
    };
```

Comment: Are there other members in the union besides the struct? If not, it seems pointless.

Comment: Can you add a link to the video?  Ideally with a hint to the relevant time?

Comment: speculation (so its in the comments) to future allow something like this: `class x{public:  union { struct {float m_x,m_y;}; struct {float test[2];};};};` Protip: unions are weird.

Comment: So far as I can tell I can't see the purpose of doing it that way.

Comment: @5gon12eder I found this from GitHub Code, Here is the Link [link](https://github.com/BSVino/MathForGameDevelopers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked out revision `2d964cbb9e5065ec327ef6e2a5f086820ed024c1` and `grep`ped for `union` and the closest match to your code sample I could find was in [`math/vector.h` following line 56](https://github.com/BSVino/MathForGameDevelopers/blob/master/math/vector.h#L56).

Cut down to the construct in question, we basically have this.  (Note that this is different from the code you are showing.)

```
struct vec3
{
  union
  {
    struct
    {
      float x;
      float y;
      float z;
    };
    float v[3];
  };
};
```

This will allow us to refer to the elements of a `vec3` either by name, as in

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec3& v3)
{
  os << "(" << v3.x << ", " << v3.y << ", " << v3.z << ")";
  return os;
}
```

or using array syntax as in

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec3& v3)
{
  os << "(";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    os << (i ? ", " : "") << v3.v[i];
  os << ")";
  return os;
}
```

While this is about as good as you can get in C, personally, I think this is poor style C++.  A more modern cleaner and equally efficient approach would use inline accessor functions and overload `operator[]`.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>

#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define DEBUG 1
#else
#  define DEBUG 0
#endif

class vec3
{
private:
  float data_[3];

public:

  constexpr vec3() noexcept : data_ {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}
  {
  }

  constexpr vec3(const float x, const float y, const float z) noexcept : data_ {x, y, z}
  {
  }

  const float& x() const noexcept { return this->data_[0]; }
  const float& y() const noexcept { return this->data_[1]; }
  const float& z() const noexcept { return this->data_[2]; }

  float& x() noexcept { return this->data_[0]; }
  float& y() noexcept { return this->data_[1]; }
  float& z() noexcept { return this->data_[2]; }

  const float&
  operator[](const std::size_t i) const noexcept(!DEBUG)
  {
    if (DEBUG && i >= 3)
      throw std::invalid_argument {"vector index out of range"};
    return this->data_[i];
  }

  float&
  operator[](const std::size_t i) noexcept(!DEBUG)
  {
    if (DEBUG && i >= 3)
      throw std::invalid_argument {"vector index out of range"};
    return this->data_[i];
  }
};
```

While this is arguably a little redundant, it will pay off by giving us a very clean and efficient interface.

Using explicit member access:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec3& v3)
{
  os << "(" << v3.x() << ", " << v3.y() << ", " << v3.z() << ")";
  return os;
}
```

Using array syntax (optionally range-checked):

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec3& v3)
{
  os << "(";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    os << (i ? ", " : "") << v3[i];
  os << ")";
  return os;
}
```

Comment: I Know I am Very late, But Thanks for the great Explanation!